# Multidimensional arrays from standard input

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, user-input

I'm trying to figure out how to read in a multidimensional array from standard input given the user provides the row and col size followed by integers of the array

e.g. Input:

```
        2 3      <= row, col of array
        8 3 10   < array integers
        7 9 6
```

My code is currently:

```
    int colA = scan.nextInt();
    int rowA = scan.nextInt();        

    int[][] array = new int[rowA][colA];

    for (int i = 0; i <rowA;i++){
        for (int j=0; j<colA;j++){
            array1[i][j] += scan.nextInt();
        } 
    }
```

And the output of my array is: [[8,3,10,7,9,6]] but what I'd like to do is output **[[8,3,10],[7,9,6]]**

Comment: So how are you outputting the array to see ```[[8,3,10,7,9,6]]``` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here first the row and col value got from users is reversed that is the only mistake i could see
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TwoDimensionalArray {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int rowA = scan.nextInt();
    int colA = scan.nextInt();

    int[][] array = new int[rowA][colA];

    for (int i = 0; i < rowA; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < colA; j++) {
            array[i][j] += scan.nextInt();
        }
    }
    for (int[] innerArray : array) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(innerArray));
    }
}
```

}
This is a working one

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors in your code.

1. You inverted the order of the dimensions asked to the users.

   Use this:

   ```
   int rowA = scan.nextInt();
   int colA = scan.nextInt();
   ```

   Instead of this:

   ```
   int colA = scan.nextInt();        
   int rowA = scan.nextInt();
   ```
2. You wrote `array1` instead of `array` in `array1[i][j] += scan.nextInt();`

Note that you can use `array[i][j] = scan.nextInt();` instead of `array[i][j] += scan.nextInt()`